# Slick carousel - images added, but not in a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

The images are added to the page and are visible, but they appear like normal inline images in HTML rather than in a carousel.

```
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-6">
            <div class="sc"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var sc = $('.sc');

    function populate() {
        getCoordinates(function (pins) {
            for (var i in pins) {
                // make markers
            }
            markers.on('click', markerClick);
            map.addLayer(markers);
        });
    }

    function markerClick(a) {
        getPlace(a.layer.placeid, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (var i in data.image_set) {
                sc.append('<div><img src="' + data.image_set[i].image + '"></div>');
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        populate();
        sc.slick({
            infinite: false
        });
    });

    function getCoordinates(callback) {
        // ajax
    }
</script>
```

Here is the rendered HTML when inspecting element:

```
<div class="sc slick-initialized slick-slider">
    <div aria-live="polite" class="slick-list draggable">
        <div class="slick-track" role="listbox" style="opacity: 1; width: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://asdf.s3.amazonaws.com:443/36x2kkGD.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please create a jsbin or Plnkr.

Comment: tbh I couldn't figure out how to use either of those tools, but I took a look at Slick carousel samples they had and if I deleted their CSS, it looked exactly that what I'm seeing with my project. So it appears that I don't have the corresponding CSS, but I have the `slick-min.css` and `slick-theme.css` in my header, and `slick.js` is appending the appropriate classes to my `sc` class.

Answer (score 0):

It's not putting the images in the carousel because I was initializing the carousel first in `$(document).ready`, and *then* adding the images in `markerClick`.

The proper way to do it is to simply initialize the carousel after loading the images like so:

```
    function markerClick(a) {
        getPlace(a.layer.placeid, function (data) {
            sc.html('');
            for (var i in data.image_set) {
                sc.append('<div><img src="' + data.image_set[i].image + '"></div>');
            }
            sc.slick({
                dots: true,
                infinite: false,
                variableWidth: true,
                speed: 150
            });
        });
    }
```